# What are the effects of frenkel and schottky defects on electrical conductivity of a solid?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

How do these two defects impact dielectric constant of solid? Please explain these two questions in detail.
In case of frenkel defect the the smaller ions are just dislocated from their initial positions. In that case the electrical conductivity must remain unaltered. But I have found out from few sources that electrical conductivity decreases due to increase in resistance so I am a bit confused.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry StackExchange. You should now give sentence or two to explain what you have found out so far otherwise this looks like a homework question and no one will answer it for you, and then  its likely to be closed.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please look into it.

Comment: @Sriharsha Nice! Your question is going to be reopened very shortly and soon you will get an answer.